# errors function is deprecated PHP 7.3.28?

Tags: php

can someone help me how to correct the following code so that I do not get a php error
thank you very much

`$skin = preg_replace_callback('/{\$lng->(.+?)}/i', create_function('$matches', 'global $LNG; return $LNG[$matches[1]];'), $skin);`

`$skin = preg_replace_callback('/{\$(.+?)}/i', create_function('$matches', 'global $TMPL; return $TMPL[$matches[1]];'), $skin);`

`$skin = preg_replace_callback('/{include \"(.+?)\"}/i', create_function('$matches', 'return file_get_contents($matches[1]);'), $skin);`

Comment: Give it a rest with the reposts. Help nagging won't yield personal support. This has been answered a hundred times over. And if you can't be bothered to read the existing posts, then well, though luck.

Comment: had answered 100 times but no solution for me